# Global decleration input [type=submit]:hover

Tags: css, hover, global

A short question, how to declare the hover effect for an input field of type submit globally?

I tried this:

```
input [type=submit]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But this does not seem to work.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yth5dsf0/)

Comment: You have a space between `input` and `[type etc]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to remove the space between `input` and `[type=submit]:hover`

```
input[type=submit]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```